# How to read values from theme css files in gtk3 after version 3.20

Tags: gtk, gtk3

In gtk3, after version 3.20 is released, a lot of Widget specific properties have been deprecated and it is advised to read those values for the particular Widget from the css. For example, in following link, for GTKScale, the slider-width property has been depricated and it is advised to read the value from the css.

https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkScale.html#GtkScale--s-slider-length
https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkScrollbar.html#GtkScrollbar--s-min-slider-length

I have a project where we are reading a lot of these values from gtk3 for specific widget for specific state like slider-length for GtkScale, min-slider-length for GtkScrollbar and many more.
I want to know how do I read these values from the css as being suggested by the documentation. I was not able to find any example for this anywhere.

I have seen that it is possible to read the full css using gtk_css_provider_get_named and then getting string representation of this css_provider. But this returns the full css of the theme and I don't think I should be parsing the css myself as this could be error prone. There should be a way to get the a particular property for specific widget for specific state flags.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`gtk_style_context_get_property()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkStyleContext.html#gtk-style-context-get-property) for this, with the name of the CSS property.

Comment: I have seen this API, but I could not find any working example, demo, sample of this. Can you point me to one? I would like to see how someone uses this.